# Build a dynamic search like apple - Simply need direction/guidance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I know this has been asked before, but I simply need educated advice on a direction to go.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and have recently upgraded to full-text search.

I'm using HTML, jQuery, and can trigger a feed that grabs results on a click event without a problem.

So I guess my primary question is, what's the best way to go about this considering server load, caching results? etc? Lots of tutorials out there but they seem to be left with... oh by the way, you should do this differently for server load, but this tutorial is just an example.

So lets say the search pertains to a directory.

- BusinessName (I.e. Taco Johns)
- BusinessDescription (I.e. We make tacos)
- BusinessKeyWords (I.e. restaurant, tacos, food)
- BusinessCategory (I.e. Restaurants)

I'm going to be using CONTAINS for the first time it seems, which I've never done before. I want the search to be smart... Display businesses within their appropriate category... so the results would need to group properly.

Any advice, direction, considerations on server performance, etc. would be greatly appreciated. Or an example of a query using contains or the best method for the above example.

```
Searchbox: What are you looking for?

Entered text: local **restaurants**
```

So the query that would evaluate the weight of the words, compare against those fields, etc.

Now lets say the above entered text resulted in lots of restaurants... what if they typed in:

Entered text: local restaurants that sell tacos

So right now I have a working dynamic search, but it's strict and jQuery only. On page load, all the businesses are captured in a jquery object, and the search parses those out as someone types. This method I know will be using SQL on each keyup, but is this the best way? Should I eventually have another separate database with all the businesses in it that the search queries to keep the load off the rest of the site?

Thank you for any advice... a bit out of my expertise here for sure.

Answer (score 0):

What I use is solr with jquery autocomplete....works well and is pretty easy to setup/get working.

Comment: It appears this is a linux based solution?